# What is the fiber in gold bond extra fibered gypsum cement plaster?

Tags: drywall, plaster, asbestos

I have a house that was built in the 50s.  In the process of taking apart the metal lathe plaster ceiling in the basement, I found some empty paper bags that labeled "Gold Bond Extra Fibered Gypsum Cement Plaster."  What is the fiber that they would use?  Can it be asbestos?

##### Edit

Here is the label and directions:

[image: Plaster Bag]

The small print in the bag at the top says something like guaranteed to meet classifications by , Pepperell, MA.

The only stamp I see that could be a date is this:

[image]

I had a sample of the ceiling tested for asbestos and it came back negative but they could have used different batches/brands.

Comment: It is possible, but would need to have tested to be sure.  Having bags from the 50s/60s a bit odd.  Regulations about asbestos and removing it can be more difficult than taking minor precautions for your health(masks, eye protection, gloves).  If the bags have any thing about fire, then it having asbestos goes way up.

Comment: Don't see anything about fire.  Just mixing/working directions and a quality guarantee.

Comment: If it has asbestos or not the precautions are the same for not breathing the stuff in.  The negative test will help a lot in getting rid of the stuff.  It becomes just plain waste instead of a bio hazard.

Comment: Cellulose fibres were used after the disuse of asbestos.  But that was more in the 1980s.